# Advanced custom fields: can't query posts by custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to query posts whose ACF field "show_on_frontpage" value is equal to "yes" (see definition of this field in screenshot below). As prescribed in [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) here's my code:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key' => 'show_on_frontpage',
  'meta_value' => 'yes'
);
$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {
  while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();
    if (get_field('show_on_frontpage')) the_field('show_on_frontpage'); ?>
  endwhile;
}
```

This returns/displays nothing. If I used instead simply `$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1);` then I get all my posts and "yes" shows up for those that have "yes" as the value of their "show_on_frontpage" field.

What's wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: Line 2 of your quoted code block is missing a comma - is this just a transcription error?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. That's not the issue though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this question/answer on the ACF forum:

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/using-checkbox-fields-in-custom-queries/

It would be better to switch your checkbox field to a True/False field instead, since it appears that your checkbox group field only contains a single option.

> Checkboxes are stored as serialized data and you’re not going to be able to use WP_Query to filter by a checkbox field.
>
> If you use a true/false field then you can use WP_Query, the values of
>   a true/false field are 0 (zero) for false and 1 for true.

So if you switched your checkbox field to a True/False field, you would rewrite your code as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'show_on_frontpage',
    'meta_value' => 1 /* or true */
);
$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();
        /* My content for each post with the checkbox checked goes here */
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe and good finding. It works now!! Just one thing: after changing the field type, the posts for which the field was set to "true" were not picked up by the query. I had to set them to "false", update, then set them to "true" again so they can be selected. Any idea why? Looks like changing a field's type messes things up a little

Comment: I'm not really sure if there's a programatic way to fix that. Certain field types with content applied don't do too well when the field type is changed to something else. Sometimes the content will translate over, and other times, you reach a situation like this. Hopefully you don't have too many pages to update in this method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use the more recent `meta_query => array()` syntax:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'show_on_frontpage',
                'value' => 'yes',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
    );

    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {

        while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();

          echo get_the_title();
          // Post stuff

        endwhile;

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Note that you need to give the post ID to the ACF helper functions `get_field()` & `the_field()` within the while loop.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

On a wider note, this article calls into question the wisdom of using post_meta keys for this purpose and is worth a read: https://tomjn.com/2016/12/05/post-meta-abuse/. The article suggests using a custom taxonomy to achieve what you need - being better for performance.

Comment: The whole point of the code I'm trying to use is that I don't select all posts, only to test which ones fulfill the criterion (waste of resources). Your $args returns all posts.

Comment: You're mistaken, it only returns posts where the 'show_on_frontpage' meta key is set to 'yes'. I can unserstand your confusion so I will modify the answer to remove the ACF conditional checks.

Comment: Sorry! The original code had a mistake (I left out the nested array, and used the wrong compare operator). I've edited the answer and it should work now.