# Query posts by custom fields

Tags: wordpress, arguments, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a website using Advanced Custom Fields that has yachts for sale. The yachts use a custom Post type called ‘yachts’

One of the fields in the individual yacht listing is a true/false value to determine wether it should be a featured listing. (it was originally a checkbox but I changed it after experimenting with the answer in this post)

[Advanced custom fields: can't query posts by custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162139/advanced-custom-fields-cant-query-posts-by-custom-field)

I am trying to display previews of the featured listings on the home page but I can’t get it to work.

I originally tried this code from the ACF documentation

**edit:** I started with just trying to fetch the title but I also need the additional fields

```
<section class="featured-yachts">
    
    <h2>FEATURED YACHTS</h2>
    
    <?php 
    
    // args
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'yachts',
        'meta_key'      => 'featured',
        'meta_value'    => 'yes'
    );
    
    
    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    
    
    
</section>
```

And now have this after switching to a true false field

```
<section class="featured-yachts">
    
    <h2>FEATURED YACHTS</h2>
    
    <?php 
    
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
    );

    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {

        while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();

          echo get_the_title();

        endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
    
    ?>
    
</section>
```

I have also tried editing this: [How filter custom posts by Advanced Custom Fields checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150315/how-filter-custom-posts-by-advanced-custom-fields-checkbox)

but again, I cant get it to work.

The most any of these return is the h3 title

I can't work out what the issue is.

Thanks in advance for any help

**edit :** I have at least one post using the custom post type 'yachts' that is set to true for featured.

I still have lots of fields to add, but I would have expected that this output the h3 title and then the title of the post marked featured.

In the end, I would like it to function much like latest post previews, but display custom fields and only if the 'featured' true/false is set to yes

I have made an ACF field called 'featured yachts' and registered the block with Gutenberg, but there are no actual ACF fields within it, it's only used to call the file 'content-featured-yachts-block.php' which has this code I am trying to fix.

I am trying to populate the post previews within this featured yachts block with data pulled from the individual yacht listings. In these listings is the 'featured' true/false option. Screen shot atttached.

[image]

This is my code for registering the CPT

```
// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {
 
    register_post_type( 'yachts',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Yacht Listings' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Yacht' ),
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'New Yacht Listing'),
                 'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Yacht Listing'),
                 'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Yacht Listing'),
                 'new_item' => __( 'New Yacht Listing'),
                 'view_item' => __( 'View Listings'),
                 'search_items' => __( 'Search Listings'),
                 'not_found' =>  __( 'No Yacht Listings Found'),
                 'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No yacht Listings found in Trash')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            // 'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'yachts'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-sos',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('category')
        )
    );
}
```

**Another edit** - I made the assumption that if I could get the title field to show, the other fields would be easy but i can't get them either so I ALSO need to work out how to add the additional fields from the listing

The code I have tried is below

```
<h2>FEATURED YACHTS</h2>

<?php 

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    ),
);

$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {

    while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    
    <?php
    get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'price', true );
    ?>

    <?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

}
?>
```

AND ALSO

```
<section class="featured-yachts">

    <h2>FEATURED YACHTS</h2>

    <?php 

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured',
                'value' => 'yes',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        ),
    );

    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_posts->have_posts()) {

        while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post();?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        
        <p><?php the_field( 'price' ); ?></p>


        <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

}

    ?>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you put expected results in your question?

Comment: @Bhautik edited

Comment: can also put some screenshot how current result look like? also with how to setup custom fields in admin?

Comment: The current result just looks like a title that says 'Featured Yachts' and nothing else. 

I will add a screenshot of the ACF fields

Comment: I have added more detail and a screenshot

Comment: So that's means posts displaying are correct but you want to display only those posts that are `Featured Yachts` am I right?

Comment: There are no posts displaying at all. Currently there are only two posts on the website. The default 'hello world' one and one I have made using a custom post type.

The one I have made is marked as true for 'featured' and therefore i would like it to show on the front page using this code. Currently nothing shows at all, not even the hello world one

I have added the register post code too

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what is different for you but it does not work - are you ale to add additional fields?

Comment: I didn't test add additional fields but I am sure there will no issue with getting them.

Comment: How would you add them? I have tried two different ways. I don't know what to do. Nothing displays at all for me.

Comment: I can debug but I need access.

Comment: Okay - I might move it to a staging server

Comment: Sure, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'meta_query' and for ACF true and false you don't have to compare with `LIKE`. Try the below code.

```
<section class="featured-yachts">

    <h2>FEATURED YACHTS</h2>
    
    <?php 
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'yachts',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featuredyacht',
                'value' => '1',
            )
        ),
    );

    $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post();

            echo "Title - ".get_the_title()."</br>";
            echo "Price - ".get_field( "price", get_the_ID() )."</br>";
            echo "Length - ".get_field( "length", get_the_ID() )."</br>";
            echo "Year built - ".get_field( "year_built", get_the_ID() )."</br>";
            echo "Capacity - ".get_field( "capacity", get_the_ID() )."</br>";

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
    
    ?>
    
</section>
```

Comment: I have managed to get ALL the yacht posts showing using this code:

https://codeshare.io/5RdQwV

But then I would need to narrow it down to only ones where the featured field value was yes

Comment: OK i will back to you.

Comment: I just tested with my given answer and working fine for me. I added 3 posts and set 2 posts as featured and now only featured posts are displaying.

Comment: Using the custom post Type setup?

Comment: Yes, Using the custom post Type setup

Comment: I don't know what to say, its not working for me :(

Comment: I have given up and made a category called featured and done it this way - thank you so much for your help

It's very frustrating as now I can't call the other fields

Comment: I hadn't got to that part yet. I didn't expect this to be so difficult.

I now need to display the other post fields like 'price'

Comment: It's should be working because I set up the same in my local and it all working fine.

Comment: Okay so I changed my field from featured to featuredyacht and your code worked! Maybe a conflict with the term featured? Thank you so much! Could you possibly show me the correct way to call one of the other fields, say the text field called 'price' - my attempts are unsuccessful 

When I am able to add a bounty tomorrow I will

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230707/discussion-between-bhautik-and-mr-toad).

Comment: Rather than using `featured` as meta field. Make it a taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple custom field parameters in your query, replace `$args` as in [Bhautik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66924593/5943594)'s answer with something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'yachts',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'featuredyacht',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => 50000,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>=',
        )
    ),
);
```

The above example fetches only `yachts` with `featuredyacht` set to `1` or `true` AND with a `price` of `50,000` or more. Adjust as needed to suit your parameters.

For example, to query featured yachts within a specific price range:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'yachts',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'featuredyacht',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 50000, 100000 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        )
    ),
);
```

The [developer documentation on WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) should be very useful to you for any further customizations.